# Base64 encoding new line

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to encode some hex values to base64 in shell script.

```
nmurshed@ugster05:~$ echo -n  "1906 1d8b fb01 3e78 5c21 85db 58a7 0bf9 a6bf 1e42 cb59 95cd 99be 66f7 8758 cf46 315f 1607 66f7 6793 e5b3 61f9 fa03 952d  9101 b129 7180 6f1d ca93 3494 55e0 0e2e" | xxd -r -p | base64
GQYdi/sBPnhcIYXbWKcL+aa/HkLLWZXNmb5m94dYz0YxXxYHZvdnk+WzYfn6A5UtkQGxKXGAbx3K
kzSUVeAOLg==
```

I get a automatic new line after 76 charecters, Is there a way to avoid that ?

Online i found, use "-n" to ignore new lines...Can anyone suggest something ?

Comment: This isn't actually a bash question -- it depends on your implementations of `xxd` and `base64`, which are provided by your operating system, not by bash.

Comment: I have a cookie value that is encoded via base64, When i decode it, i get 64 hex values....now I am trying to encode it back to gt that cookie value...There should not be any newline...

Comment: ...also, `echo -n` is actually (per the POSIX standard for echo) undefined behavior; for instance, if `set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo` has been run, the command `echo -n hello` will emit `-n hello` on its output. Consider `printf` if you want reliable and consistent behavior, and see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`echo -n` doesn't actually matter here: It controls whether there's a newline on the output from `echo`, but whether `echo` emits a newline has no bearing on whether `xxd` or `base64` emit newlines.

Because `xxd` ignores any trailing newline in the input, `echo` or `echo -n` will behave precisely the same here; whether there's a newline by `echo` makes no difference, because that newline (if it exists) will be consumed  by `xxd` when reading its input. Rather, what you ultimately care about is the output of `base64`, which is what is generating your final result.

---

Assuming you have the GNU version of base64, add `-w 0` to disable line wrapping in its output. Thus:

```
printf '%s' "1906 1d8b fb01 3e78 5c21 85db 58a7 0bf9 a6bf 1e42 cb59 95cd 99be 66f7 8758 cf46 315f 1607 66f7 6793 e5b3 61f9 fa03 952d  9101 b129 7180 6f1d ca93 3494 55e0 0e2e" \
  | xxd -r -p \
  | base64 -w 0
```

Comment: Thanks...well it solved my 1st doubts of many...thanks again for such a prompt reply.

Comment: `echo "foo" | base64 -w 0; echo "bar" | base64 -w 0` returns both results concatenated onto one line.  `echo "foo" | base64 -w 99999; echo "bar" | base64 -w 99999` will return 2 lines, 1 line for each result.  This is useful if you have a list of strings you want to `base64`.

Comment: At that point, I'd prefer `base64 -w 0 <<<"foo"; echo; base64 -w 0 <<<"bar"; echo` to make things explicit -- that way you don't have a corner case around content that base64-encodes to a string longer than 99,999 characters.

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar problem where 
`var1=$(echo -n "$USER:$PASSWORD" | base64)`
was resulting in an erroneous base64 encoded value which was unusable in my next step of the script, used printf & it worked fine. Here is my code:

```
var1=$(printf "%s" "${USER}:${PASSWORD}" | base64)
```